# Python: Decoding a JSON record ignoring a internal key

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have to convert a JSON input to CSV, this would be easy if the records where flat.
However each record is written this way:

```
'accountNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'}, 'subscriberNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'},
```

What is the best way to ignore' or remove the keys 'values' so the records would be like this?

```
'accountNumber':  b'8764622708', 'subscriberNumber': b'8764622708',
```

**UPDATE**

The solution using dictionary comprehension works, but I need to add more cases because there were more types of fields in my json.

```
{k:v["value"] if v is not None and type(v) is dict and "value" in v else v if type(v) is dict and "value" not in v else v for (k,v) in message_value.items() }
```

However, now I need to figure out a way to do it recursively because there are recordes withing records with this tag 'value'inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try a dictionary comprehension here since it is practically a dictionary:

```
d1 = {'accountNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'}, 'subscriberNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'}}
```

Then a comprehension like this:

```
{k:v["value"] for (k,v) in d1.items()}
```

Would give you this:

```
{'accountNumber': b'8764622708', 'subscriberNumber': b'8764622708'}
```

Edit:

This would solve the problem if there are None values at some point that cause type error:

```
d2 = {'accountNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'}, 'subscriberNumber': {'value': b'8764622708'},'foo': None}
```

Dictionary comprehension with an if-else condition.

```
{k:v["value"] for k,v in d2.items() if v is not None}
```

I would customize the conditions, etc depending on the case.

```
{'accountNumber': b'8764622708', 'subscriberNumber': b'8764622708'}
```

Comment: This should work. but I'm getting TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. I believe it is because I have some keys with no value in it, with only None.

Comment: I have made an edit to answer reflect your feedback. I hope it would be useful.